# How to use printed bricks from set 850425 into LDD?

Tags: ldd

I would like to know if it is possible to use the printed tiles (those with letters) from the [850425](http://brickset.com/sets/850425-1/Desk-Business-Card-Holder) set into the Lego Digital Designer (LDD)?

[image]

And if it is possible, the next question is "how" of course. :)

Comment: There is a method of adding custom decals into ldd using the app files but I'm not completely sure on it. I think it uses something called "Povwin"

Comment: https://github.com/chicks-net/lego-business-card-holder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not possible to add printed tiles in LDD. The closest you can get is just putting plates into the design and adding stickers.